# INNO Setup: Defining Configuration Files in Setup Package

Tags: inno-setup

This is probably a simple fix but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.  I have an app to install that will need the user to select 1 of 3 possible INI files to accompany the install.  I could easily do 3 different setups, each using a different INI but I would like to simplify matters and just give the user the choice of INI at the time of install.  The INI files have the same name, so when packaged they will have to be given different names.  Once the user selects which INI to install, it would be extracted into the app directory and renamed.  Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add entries for all three INI files to the **[Files]** section, give them the same destination name, and use the `Check` parameter to decide at runtime which single one gets installed. A snippet from one of my install scripts:

```
[Files]
Source: "{src}\Line1.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "Line.ini"; \
    Flags: external; Check: IsLine1
Source: "{src}\Line2.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "Line.ini"; \
    Flags: external; Check: IsLine2
Source: "{src}\Line3.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "Line.ini"; \
    Flags: external; Check: IsLine3
```

And the support functions in the **[Code]** section:

```
function IsLine(ID: integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := (ID = 1 + LinePage.SelectedValueIndex);
end;

function IsLine1(): boolean;
begin
  Result := IsLine(1);
end;

function IsLine2(): boolean;
begin
  Result := IsLine(2);
end;

function IsLine3(): boolean;
begin
  Result := IsLine(3);
end;
```

where `LinePage` is a custom page of type `TInputOptionWizardPage`. The user selects with a radio group for which production line the program is to be installed, and only the matching INI file is copied. Note that they are `external` in my case, but they could just as well be compiled into the setup.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to create a [Run] section (or add to it) and execute (AfterInstall: parameter) a Pascal routine that delete the extra ini files and rename the remaining one.

Comment: Thanks!  I will check into that and see what I can do.